# Implicitly creating an instance of a class that is located in a dependent dll

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Let's say you are developing a third-party DLL called `"ThirdParty.dll"` which has a class called `JustTryToInstantiateMe`. Let's say your customer has an EXE that has a reference to `"ThirdParty.dll"` or maybe the EXE doesn't have a reference to `"ThirdParty.dll"` but the EXE can find `"ThirdParty.dll"` in the PATH if somehow requested. You have no control over the EXE as you are the vendor for the `"Thirdparty.dll"` and you can only modify what the DLL does. Your customer, the one writing the EXE, agrees to either make a reference to your DLL or put your DLL in the PATH. Nothing more.

Is there a way to instantiate `JustTryToInstantiateMe` when running the EXE without explicitly using `new` or invoking a static/Shared method/field/property?

Maybe just using the static/Shared constructor somehow? Maybe on `AssemblyLoad()` event? Maybe using the registry? a startup process? Looking for ideas...

Comment: Have you considered [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: if Justtrytoinstantiate me is a static class the private static constructor will automatically be called when you try to use the class. all you will need is a using statement(C#) in your code file. `using ThirdParty;`

Comment: Both of those suggestions ASSUME that the EXE knows about "JustTryToInstantiateMe". As stated in the question that is not the case. The EXE could find "ThirdParty.dll" in the PATH if it somehow was instructed to look by the clr but there is no code in the EXE directly referencing "JustTryToInstantiateMe"

Comment: @RadioSpace - Are you sure that last part is true? Without knowing for sure, I would imagine the compiler would be smart enough to know that the type doesn't actually get used, and thus would not call static constructors. Just curious.

Comment: How do you know what class you want to instantiate? Do you have "JustTryToInstantiateMe" as a string at least? You can enumerate all types in an assembly and create instances using reflection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx

Comment: @pep you're correct, a `using` directive is not enough to call a static constructor: it won't be called until the class is actually used.

Comment: @RadioSpace sorry, thats incorrect, a static class won't be constructed until one of its static members is referenced.

Comment: @RonBeyer , @p e p thats what I meant by "try to use the class" and you can't call a static constructor. they are private. which is why it is  a implicit way of calling the static constructor upon use. ya follow.

Comment: @Denis i am are assuming the EXE is a project and not an assembly that is loaded dynamically at run time. although it is not clear in the question what approach is being taken to work with the EXE

Comment: @RadioSpace, no, the "all you need is a using statement" is the part thats incorrect, you actually need to call a member. Its just confusing because you make it sound like all you need to do is put a using statement in there and the class will be created because its static.

Comment: @RonBeyer ya know....   I see what you are saying now. to bad I can't edit that.  oh well, I hope I clearified enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From research I found out that the simple answer to this question is that this is not possible. The short answer is that in order for a class in a DLL to be loaded the class needs to be referenced by something. If a DLL were able to self-load itself by virtue of JUST being in the PATH this would bring about all kinds of security issues.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest way I know how to do this is to dynamically load the assembly and then invoke a method from an instance of a class that you create.

Here is a template in c# for the code:

```
        //add using for system.reflection
        String className = "[NAME OF CLASS WITH FULL NAMESPACE GOES HERE]";
        String methodName = "[METHOD NAME GOES HERE]"
        String dllPath = "[FILE PATH FOR DLL GOES HERE]";

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        object context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        //optionally set up parameters here
        object[] parameters = new object[0];
        String result = (String) method.Invoke(context, parameters);
```

For example, I could create a class like so (I know, it's VB, but what follows after is C#.

```
        Public Class my_class
            Private hello = "hello world"
            Public Function gethello()
                Return hello
            End Function
        End Class
```

Then after it is compiled, I can use the following code in C# to do what I think it is you are asking:

```
        //using system.reflection
        String className = "mytestlibrary.my_class";
        String dllPath = "...mytestlibrary.dll";
        String methodName = "gethello";
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        object context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        object[] parameters = new object[0];
        String result = (String) method.Invoke(context, parameters);
        //result is "hello world"
```

Now, if you want to do the same, but with an already compiled EXE file, then the code is hardly different, but you will need to create a desktop/console application to shell the other executable and properly namespace your DLL. So in YOUR application, add the following code to grab an instance of a class from the DLL referenced inside the EXE.

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        String className = "My_Class";
        String ExePath = "[PATH TO EXE]";
        String methodName = "gethello";
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(ExePath);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        object context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        object[] parameters = new object[0];
        String result = (String) method.Invoke(context, parameters);
```

It is also possible for you to dynamically load assemblies into the EXE, but that is a bit more tricky, so I will leave it at this for now unless you really need to dynamically load your DLL into the EXE.

Comment: This reflection approach makes sense but you will need to put this in the EXE. That is not allowed. You can't modify the EXE, you only have the ability to modify the code that goes into the DLL.

Comment: Ah, I got it backwards. I will run a test and see what the result are.

Comment: @Denis, you actually  can add assemblies to an already compiled executable and use those new assemblies to modify how the program executes. You cannot change code, but to some extent you can override it.

Comment: BTW, any feedback since my last edit? If I were given the same challenge, the code above is how I would handle it.

Comment: Let me know, please, if there is any more help I can give. I will update my answer to spec. -cheers :)